unable to create home directory for new user using Ansible
i try to use ansible ldap for connet my domain lab.local to my redhat 9.4 servers. isuccess to connect with my domain user but i can't create a home diretory in /home/%u, i have this error message "Could not chdir to home directory /home/trio01: No such file or "
this is my integration file:
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    pkgs:
      - sssd
      - sssd-tools
      - sssd-ldap
      - sssd-ad
      - adcli
      - realmd
      - krb5-workstation
      - openldap-clients
      - cyrus-sasl-gssapi
      - oddjob
      - oddjob-mkhomedir

    AD_Domain: LAB.LOCAL
    AD_Domain_alt: lab.local
    Join_OU: OU=Linux,DC=LAB,DC=LOCAL
    SRV_ADM_GRP_OU: OU=Linux,DC=lab,DC=local

  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: "Veuillez entrer votre nom d'utilisateur AD admin?"
      private: no
    - name: password
      prompt: "Veuillez entrer le mot de passe d'utilisateur AD admin?"
      private: yes
    - name: adhostname
      prompt: "Veuillez entrer le nom simple de la machine , pas de format fqdn format"
      private: no


  tasks:
  - name: V�rification de la version de distribution du serveur (RedHat)
    fail:
      msg: Le system ne n'�xecute pas RedHat, arr�t
    when: ansible_facts['distribution'] != 'RedHat'

      # - name: Installation des packages n�cessaires pour joindre le domaine AD
      # yum: name={{ pkgs }} state=present update_cache=yes

  - name: Configuration du nom de la machine
    shell: hostnamectl set-hostname {{ adhostname }}.{{ AD_Domain_alt }}

  - name: Int�gration au domaine  AD  (cr�ation du compte AD computer et mise a jour du fichier  /etc/krb5.keytab)

    shell: echo '{{ password }}' | adcli join --stdin-password {{ AD_Domain }} -v -U {{ username }} --domain-ou={{ Join_OU }}

  - name: Configuration du fichier sssd.conf
    template:
      src: sssd.j2
      dest: /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0600

  - name: Ensure PAM configuration for mkhomedir
    lineinfile:
     path: /etc/pam.d/common-session
     line: 'session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077'
     create: yes

  - name: Ensure oddjobd service is enabled and started
    service:
     name: oddjobd
     enabled: yes
     state: started
  - name: Configuration du fichier nsswitch.conf
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/nsswitch.conf
      regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
      line: "{{ item.line }}"
    loop:
      - regexp: '^passwd:'
        line: 'passwd:   compat sss'
      - regexp: '^group:'
        line: 'group:   compat sss'
      - regexp: '^services:'
        line: 'services:   files sss'
      - regexp: '^sudoers:'
        line: 'sudoers:   files sss'

  - name: Autorisation du group des Admin Linux AD  a se connecter aux serveurs Linux
    shell: realm permit -g adminlinux@lab.Local

  - name: Ajout du groupe Admin Linux dans sudoers
    lineinfile:
       dest: /etc/sudoers
       line: '"%adminlinux@lab.local"   ALL=(ALL) ALL'
       insertafter: '^%wheel'

  - name: Configuration du fichier krb5.conf
    template:
      src: krb5.j2
      dest: /etc/krb5.conf
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0644

  - name: Configuration du client ldap.conf
    template:
      src: ldap.j2
      dest: /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0644

  - name: Restart  daemon realm
    systemd:
     name: realmd
     enabled: yes
     state: restarted

  - name: Restart daemon SSSD
    systemd:
     name: sssd
     enabled: yes
     state: restarted
    become: yes
    become_user: root

and this is my file ssd.j2:
[sssd]
domains = {{ AD_Domain }}
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo, ssh
default_domain_suffix = {{ AD_Domain }}

[nss]
filter_users = root
filter_groups = root

[pam]

pam_mkhomedir = True

[sudo]

[domain/{{ AD_Domain }}]
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad
ad_domain = {{ AD_Domain }}
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = false
default_shell = /bin/bash
create_homedir = true
override_homedir = /home/%u
ldap_referrals = false
ldap_schema = ad
krb5_realm = {{ AD_Domain }}
dyndns_update = true
dyndns_refresh_interval = 43200
dyndns_update_ptr = true
dyndns_ttl = 3600
dyndns_auth = GSS-TSIG
enumerate = false
use_fully_qualified_names = true
skel_dir = /etc/skel
ldap_id_mapping = true
auto_private_groups = true
sudo_provider = ad
simple_allow_groups = %adminlinux@lab.local
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive

[global]
krb5_auth = yes


is the mkhomedir module enabled in /etc/sysconfig/authconfig ?

i don't have authconfig in /etc/sysconfig/  , but the service oddjobd is enabled

Then you might have to use pam_oddjob_mkhomedir instead of pam_mkhomedir; also I don't see oddjob-mkhomedir in the packages

sorry, i update my code, i will try now

always the some error : "Could not chdir to home directory /home/trio01: No such file or directory"

yes, i changed to pam_oddjob_mkhomedir

Just to be sure, what version of RedHat is it?


name: Configure pam_oddjob_mkhomedir for sshd
ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
path: /etc/pam.d/sshd
line: 'session required pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077'
create: yes
name: Configure pam_oddjob_mkhomedir for login
ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
path: /etc/pam.d/login
line: 'session required pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077'
create: yes
name: Configure pam_oddjob_mkhomedir for system-auth
lineinfile:
path: /etc/pam.d/system-auth
line: 'session required pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077' create: yes


it's rhel 9.4 , i find solution, we should add this line in yml config :

we should add this line to .yml code for config the others param:
- name: Configure pam_oddjob_mkhomedir for sshd
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/pam.d/sshd
    line: 'session required pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077'
    create: yes

- name: Configure pam_oddjob_mkhomedir for login
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/pam.d/login
    line: 'session required pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077'
    create: yes

- name: Configure pam_oddjob_mkhomedir for system-auth
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/pam.d/system-auth
    line: 'session required pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0077'
    create: yes

